# Filtering stats: What are some good patterns to follow for filtering a time/date range?

Tags: filter, time

Im looking for some good patterns of how to filter date/time in a graph. It doesnt need to be specific dates, more like day, week, month. [image]

Comment: I think your question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 4):

**Date selector**

The normal approach is to provide 2 dates that may be set individually with a date selector or by entering the dates manually.

[image]
Se more examples here: http://ui-patterns.com/users/1/collections/553/entry/2964

---

**Predefined ranges**

In addition to these date fields, it is very handy to provide some predefined ranges.  When the user selects one of these predefined suggestions, the date fields should be set to the correct dates to reflect the selection from the list.

*The suggestions in this list depends on the purpose your product.*

For reporting tools (eg. training log, working hours, phone call history):

- Today
- Yesterday
- This week
- Last week
- This month
- Last month

For planning tools (eg. traveling, TV-shows):

- Today
- Tomorrow
- This weekend
- Next Monday
- Next Tuesday
- Next Wednesday
- Next Thursday
- Next Friday

A weird proposal for some imaginary photo album software:

- My wifes birthday ± 2 days
- My kids birthday ± 2 days
- My mothers birthday ± 2 days
- Christmas eve
- Thanksgiving
- Halloween
- The easter holidays
- The winter holidays
- The summer holidays

Comment: You could also scan for heavy activity and suggest those or suggest date ranges with discounts etc.